# adding class on a random list item

Tags: jquery, random

I have an unordered list with list items.
I have a class called 'active', which I want randomly be added on a list item. I now have this:

```
// I want this class added on a random list item
$("#gallery li:first-child").addClass("on");
```

Math.random?

Comment: Thank you all for the quick replies! I randomly (:p) picked a right answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);

var $li = $("#gallery li");
$li.eq(random % $li.length).addClass("on");
```

Answer (score 5):

Try something like below,

```
var $li = $('#gallery li');
$li.eq(Math.floor(Math.random()*$li.length)).addClass("on");
```

**Edit:** Updated to avoid re-query DOM for `li`

Answer (score 1):

```
var licount = $("#gallery li").length;
var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*(licount+1));

$("#gallery li:nth-child("+randomnumer+")").addClass("on");
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Math.random`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) is how you get random numbers, so all you need to do is get a number between `0` and the number of `<li>`s (minus 1), and add the class to that.

```
var $lis = $("#gallery li");
$lis.eq( Math.floor( Math.random() * $lis.length ) ).addClass("on");
```

Answer (score 0):

if you know the number of li (here 10 li)

```
rand=Math.floor(Math.random() * 10); // 0 to 9
$("#gallery li").get(rand).addClass("on");
```

else

```
var $li=$("#gallery li");
rand=Math.floor(Math.random() * $li.length()); // 
$li.eq(rand).addClass("on");
```

Comment: You need to use `.eq()`, not `.get()`.  `.get()` returns a DOM element, not a jQuery object.

Comment: @rocket sorry I correct my code before you comment but thank you :)